# Pointer changes value after exiting constructor

Tags: c++, string

For some reason, whenever it reassigns the string as a different const char*, it has an error. After it creates a new buffer on a string with a previous buffer, when it exists the constructor the buffer changes value for no reason. I am using heap memory, so it shouldn't be affected by scope.

```
#include <iostream>

class String {
private:
    char* buffer;
    unsigned int size;
public:
    String(const char* string) {
        size = strlen(string);
        buffer = new char[size + 1];
        memcpy(buffer, string, size + 1);
        buffer[size] = 0;
    }
    String(const String& other) {
        memcpy(this, new String(other.buffer), sizeof(String));
    }
    ~String() {
        delete buffer;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const String& str);

    String operator+(const String& other) {
        unsigned int nSize = this->size + other.size;
        char* nBuffer = new char[nSize + 1];
        memcpy(nBuffer, this->buffer, nSize + 1);
        strcat(nBuffer, other.buffer);
        nBuffer[nSize] = 0;

        return String(nBuffer);
    }

    void operator+=(const String& other) {
        unsigned int nSize = this->size + other.size;
        char* nBuffer = new char[nSize + 1];
        memcpy(nBuffer, this->buffer, nSize + 1);
        strcat(nBuffer, other.buffer);
        nBuffer[nSize] = 0;

        this->~String();
        memcpy(this, new String(nBuffer), sizeof(String));
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const String& str) {
    stream << str.buffer;
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    String test1 = "Hello";
    test1 = "there";

    std::cout << test1 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: To start with, the copy constructor is wrong.  Don't ever use `memcpy(this`.  It is almost always wrong.

Comment: You've got a really weird copy ctor there.

Comment: How so? I'm very new to this low level programming.

Comment: What do you think this memcpy does? Your regular constructor does a `new`. And your regular destructor does a `delete`. You can only `delete` what's been `new`ed, and ***exactly once***. So, when the copied object, the copy-constructed one gets destroyed, its destructor gets invoked, which expects to `delete` something. So, can you explain at which point, in this process, something got `new`ed, which will now be `delete`d? Counting on my fingers, I count one `new`, and two `delete`s. Does this make sense to you? And what about the assignment operator? What are your plans for it?

Comment: In addition to the main issue that I addressed in my answer, you have other problems here. Namely using `delete buffer` where it should be `delete[] buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

`test1 = "there"` is the same as `test1 = String("there")` because the string `"there"` has to be converted to a `String`. The default assignment operator works by assigning all the members on the right hand side to the members on the left hand side. It does a *shallow* copy of all the members, so your strings are not actually duplicated, but rather both `buffer` pointers in `test1` and `String("there")` point to the same memory location that holds the string `"there"`.

At the end of the assignment the `String("there")` object has to be destroyed, so it calls the destructor which `delete`s the memory that its `buffer` is pointing to. At the end of the `main()` method the same happens with `test1`, only when it gets there it finds that the memory has already been deleted, causing a runtime error.

When dealing with raw pointers as class members, in addition to making your own copy-constructor you also have to make your own copy-assignment operator to delete the already held memory and allocate new memory. A simply one may look like this:

```
String& operator=(String const& other) {
  delete[] buffer;
  buffer = new char[other.size + 1];
  strcpy(buffer, other.buffer);
  size = other.size;
  return *this;
}
```

Now assigning into `test1` will allocate an entirely seperate memory space to hold the string.

Comment: Awesome. Didn't even realize I could overload the assignment operator. Works!